# PostgresSql Related Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column named "activity", and I have 3 kinds of activities inside the "activity" column. 1.Completed_order, 2.viewed_page, 3.email.
Now, I want to write a query where I will get the activity_id of the first 'email' which occurred after every 'completed_order" activity.

The query I have written is

```
select 
        activity_id, ts, customer,activity,
        case 
        when activity = 'email' and lag(activity) over (partition by customer order by ts) !='email' 
        then activity_id else 0 
        end as cndn
        from activity_stream as az1 where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand' and customer in (select customer from activity_stream where activity='email') order by ts
```

[The results I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l3T2.png)

[And the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJEL.png)

The Output should
activity_id of a minimum "email" activity, that occurred in between each "completed_order" activity in a "completed_order" activity row.

Comment: Please update the question by posting the sample data that produces the desired results, as text - **no images** (or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) . Further post the current and desired results also as text. See "[Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)"

Comment: Ok, but I couldn't explain the desired result through text. that is why I attached a picture

Comment: If needed images can be used in addition to the text, but not a replacement.

Comment: Actually, I am new here so that's why I am not getting exactly what you are trying to say. Sorry  but I have updated the question as you said. Please check. 

Comment: What you are being asked to do is show the expected and actual results as editable text in the question - ideally by copying and pasting but if you have to manually type it in then thats what you'll need to do. Then all the information can be seen in one go

Comment: OK, Got it! thanks :)
can I show the results in both text and image format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a subquery like this achieve what you want?

```sql
select activity_id, ts, customer, activity,
case when activity = 'completed_order' then (select activity_id from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'email' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1) else 0 end as cndn
from activity_stream as a 
where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand' 
and customer in (select customer from activity_stream where activity='email') 
order by ts
```

EDIT:
just seen you edited the question, this will only get the first email activity after the completed_order row, it wont be specific to the activity that occured between each completed_order row.

EDIT 2:
this should work but its dirty my postgresql isn't the best:

```sql
select activity_id, ts, customer, activity,
case when a.activity = 'completed_order' then
  case when (select ts from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'completed_order' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1) is null then (select activity_id from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'email' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1)
    when (select ts from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'email' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1) < (select ts from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'completed_order' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1) then (select activity_id from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b. activity = 'email' and a.ts < b.ts limit 1)
  end 
end as cndn
from activity_stream as a 
where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand' 
and customer in (select customer from activity_stream where activity='email') 
order by ts
```

EDIT 3: I've refactored it so you can change `order by b.ts desc` at the end of line 3 to be either `asc` for the minimum or `desc` for the maximum email activity_id.

```sql
select a.activity_id, a.ts, a.customer, a.activity,
case when a.activity = 'completed_order' then
  (select b.activity_id from activity_stream b where a.customer = b.customer and b.activity = 'email' and b.ts between a.ts and (select c.ts from activity_stream c where a.customer = c.customer and c.activity = 'completed_order' and a.ts < c.ts limit 1) order by b.ts desc limit 1)
end as cndn
from activity_stream as a 
order by ts
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.
Yes, I want to get only the 1st email activity that occurred between each 'completed_order' activity but the activity_id of the first email should be in a completed_order activity row. if there is no 'email' activity between 'completed_order' activities then it should be null.

Comment: Just saw your edited Query. yes, it is somehow correct but I am also getting the minimum activity_id of email in a first completed_order row although there is no email in between completed order.

Comment: 11089 "1996-08-12 " "Leh" "completedorder" 11077
10279 "1996-08-13 " "Leh " "completedorder" 11077
11077 "1996-08-14 " "Leh" "email" 0
11088 "1996-08-18 " "Leh " "viewedpage" 0
10284 "1996-08-19 " "Leh" "completedorder" 11078
11078 "1996-08-20 " "Leh" "email" 0
11080 "1996-10-21 " "Leh" "email" 0
10343 "1996-10-31 " "Leh" "completedorder" 11091
11090 "1996-11-01 " "Leh" "viewedpage" 0
11091 "1996-11-02 " "Leh" "email" 0
10497 "1997-04-04 " "Leh" "completedorder"

Comment: This is the result I am getting. the first 2 rows are completed_order rows that mean there is no email activity between these rows. still, I am getting the activity_id in a first row

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much. 
I am getting the result I wanted. :) but can you please briefly explain what logic you have used? it will be easier for other people as well. Thanks again.

Comment: if the next completed_order row does not exist, return next email row, if the next completed_order row is later than the next email row return email row else return null

Comment: Also in this query, I wanted to get the min email activity_id. what if I want to get the maximum email id between every completed_order activity? what changes can I make in this query?

Comment: Great Logic, thanks again. A big thumbs up. :)

Comment: maximum date would be more difficult, you will need to get the next completed_order row, then get all email rows between current completed_order row and next completed_order row and select the latest. Do you need this query?

Comment: Yes, I need it. Can you write it?

Comment: edited my answer, refactored code to give you both with a slight change.

Comment: Thank you so much. yes, it is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output you are trying to create a calculated value for the completed row, not the email row - so use the LEAD function on the completed row not the lag function on the email row

Comment: No, I want to get the activity_id of the minimum ts of 'email' activity after every completed_order in a different column called cndn

Comment: The image for what you want is showing that the new column is populated for the completed record not the email record - is that not what you want? If is then you need to calculate the value for the completed record but use the value from the next email record, which you do using the lead function

Comment: I want to show the activity_id of the 1st email, that occurred after every 'completed_order' activity, in a 'completed_order' row.
if there is no email activity between completed_order activities, it will be null in a completed_order row.